# Assign empty string only if variable is nil (ternary operator)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, variable-assignment

I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of the following C# code:

```
someStringValue = someStringValue ?? string.Empty;
```

Where if `someStringValue` is null, a value of `string.Empty` (the empty string: `""`) will be assigned.  How do I achieve this in Objective-C?  Is my only option:

```
if(!someStringValue)
   someStringValue = @"";
```

***Solution thanks to @Dave DeLong***:

```
someStringValue = someStringValue ?: @"";
```

Comment: I feel that the `if` version is much more simple and readable in Obj-C.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simple, using ternary operator.

```
someStringValue = someStringValue ? someStringValue : @"";
```

Or if you want a macro, you can do that too.

```
#if !defined(StringOrEmpty)
    #define StringOrEmpty(A)  ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __a ? __a : @""; })
#endif
```

Sample usage:

```
someStringValue = StringOrEmpty(someStringValue);
```

Comment: ... or even just `someStringValue = someStringValue ?: @"";`

Comment: Thank you, Eric. This is what I was hoping for. @Dave DeLong, thank you as well for streamlining it, I ultimately went with your implementation.

Comment: @DaveDeLong My experience was JavaScript has taught me to avoid apocryphal operators. Even if I know what it is, my teammates probably won't and I'd rather it be immediately obvious. That having been said, +1 for the awesome tip. I had been missing the old `a = b || c` notation and that's just what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If someStringValue is a class variable, you could add this code to your .m file that owns the string

```
- (void)setSomeStringValue:(NSString *)newSomeStringValue
{
   if (!newSomeStringValue) newSomeStringValue = @"";
   _someStringValue = newSomeStringValue;
}
```

Comment: I thing is more clean override getter, not setter.